# Invariant Violation: eventType argument is required when `goBack()` React Navigation 5

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation-v5

i am using `"@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.3",` and trying to use Hooks but unfortunately i am getting error `Invariant Violation: eventType argument is required.` when trying to pop i.e `goBakc()` called
Basically i have all of my screen in a `single stack` and  i am trying to use hook in my child component let say `Header.tsx` which is being used in all over the project.

code for it really simple.

```
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native"
const { goBack } = useNavigation()
```

and onPress i am just calling.

> onPress={() => goBack()}

[image: error can be seen in the screensot]

Comment: first you have a navigation props in the stack header so pass it in your component and you can  access it like normal props.navigation.goBack() if u can understand share your code header and stack file code so I can solve your problem.

Comment: basically, i am trying to use hooks and react-navigation provide `useNavigation` hook from which we can use  in any component so, we don't need to pass it in the child component, i am just going to add screen shot for my problem

Answer (score 0):

It was not due to the `goBack()` or navigation issue
I was using some native modules and adding/subscribing a custom event, for removing it `eventEmitter.removeAllListeners()` which was the cause of crash
Just replaced  it with `eventEmitter.removeListener('CustomeEventName', () => {})`